# Why does there have a transparent but small top panel in application developed in Java?

Tags: java, linux, swing, javafx

look at top panel:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRAbb.gif]

I am developing a application like alfred using javafx.
As you can see,there is a transparent top panel.There is also a same problem when using swing. My development environment is as follows.

- OS: Arch Linux
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.8.13-1-ARCH
- WM: i3
- Java: "1.8.0_102"

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = new Parent() {
      };
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: in general if you want answers here you should paste a runnable example

Comment: Right,i will pay attention to that.

Comment: You said you'd pay attention to the comment recommending posting a [mcve], however you didn't [edit] the question for at least  4 hours. Voting for close now, since the code to reproduce the issue is not posted in the question.

Comment: I don'r see any transparent border in Win 10.

Comment: It is ok in Windows,please notice my environment mentioned above.

Comment: I had found the cause that compton,a compositor for X,has a feature "Titlebar/frame transparency".

Answer (score 0):

I had found the cause that compton,a compositor for X,has a feature "Titlebar/frame transparency". – z10030313335